# is close browser method in watir clears the cache or cookies added in during the test?

Tags: cookies, automated-tests, watir, watir-webdriver

I have created automated test for remember login credintials in website using watir.

In the test Scenario after closing the browser to reopen it again and checking if it will open the home page or not. The test redirects to login so I want to ask:

is close browser method in watir clears the cache or cookies added in during the test?

Answer (score 5):

By default, when `Watir::Browser.new` is called, it creates a new profile with new local storage for cookies and cache.

When `browser.quit` or `browser.close` is called, it destroys the temporary profile. It does not explicitly handle cookies or the cache, however these are eliminated when the temporary profile is deleted.

You can verify this by opening up `irb` and doing the following:

```rb
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'about:cache'
```

Observe the path for the `Cache Directory`. For me, it looks like `/var/folders/fq/cjndhx054dj9kr6bls20pnh00000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140707-75724-15rrd9b/Cache`.

Now do the following in `irb`.

```rb
browser.quit
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'about:cache'
```

Observe the path is different.

To reuse just cookies you could store the cookies in an instance or global variable prior to calling browser.quit and then restore the cookies later, after the new browser is instantiated. I use code similar to the following for a test that makes sure a 'Remember Me' box is checked on a login form.

```rb
# First test
browser = Watir::Browser.new
# browser logs in ...
$my_cookies = browser.cookies.to_a
browser.quit

# Second test
browser = Watir::Browser.new
$my_cookies.each do |cookie|
  browser.cookies.add(cookie[:name], cookie[:value])
end
browser.goto 'my-test-site.com'
# test that username is remembered
```

I believe it is possible to use a specific profile, while maintaining settings, cache, and cookies by creating a `Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new` and passing the profile as an argument to `Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => <my_profile_object>`.

More on profiles can be found on [Watir Webdriver Firefox Profiles](http://watir.github.io/docs/firefox/); [Cookie](http://watir.github.io/docs/cookies/) information is also available, but is not very complete. Updated links now included as of 2016-12-13.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. And I would like to mention that in second test I needed to go to my domain before adding the cookies then revisit the domain again to reflect the cookies in the domain.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like .close may handle cookies as shown in the close method description from GitHUb

```
def close
  return if @closed
  @driver.quit
  @closed = true
end
alias_method :quit, :close # TODO: close vs quit

#
# Handles cookies.
#
# @return [Watir::Cookies]
#
```

I am not seeing anything about caches however.

Comment: The "close method description" that you are referring to is actually the description for the `cookies` method. The method descriptions come before the method. The close method description is just "Closes browser."